# d3.js and dimple.js two identical elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, d3.js, dimple.js

I created a chart using the dimple.js library with the following code:

```
var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
var x = myChart.addMeasureAxis("x", "x-measure");
x.tickFormat = "%";
var y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "y-measure");
y.tickFormat = "%";
myChart.addSeries(["Attribute", "Category"], dimple.plot.scatter);
myChart.draw();
```

I'm trying to use d3 to select the x and y axes of the chart to alter them, but the html elements are pretty much identical, so I don't know how to select them individually. Using `d3.select('.dimple-axis').attr("id","x-axis");` I've been able to add a unique identifier to the x-axis (the first element listed), but I have no way of selecting the y-axis.

Here's the HTML code:

X-Axis: `<g class="dimple-axis" transform="translate(0, 540)" id="x-axis" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 10px;">...</g>`

Y-Axis: `<g class="dimple-axis" transform="translate(140, 0)" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 10px;">...</g>`

Any ideas on how to add an unique id to the y-axis permanently, or somehow select it using d3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know dimplejs, but on [the examples](http://dimplejs.org/examples_index.html) provided on their web site, it seems that X and Y axes have respective CSS classes `dimple-axis-x` and `dimple-axis-x`.

Maybe you should try to update your version of dimplejs?

Comment: Yes, that did the trick!! I had no idea I was using an older version. Thanks so much!!